# Setting up multiple checkbox for grading test but cant get the values of the checkbox to display

Tags: c#

This is the code I have been trying to get working:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // pullups
    int checkbox1 = 0;
    int checkbox2 = +1;
    int checkbox3 = +1;
    int checkbox4 = +1;
    int checkbox5 = +1;
    int checkbox6 = +1;
    int checkbox7 = +1;
    // encrochments
    int checkbox8 = +2;
    int checkbox9 = +2;
    int checkbox10 = +2;
    int checkbox11 = +2;
    int checkbox12 = +2;
    int checkbox13 = +2;
    int checkbox14 = +2;
    // GOAL
    int checkbox15 = 0;
    int checkbox16 = +13;
    int checkbox17 = +13;
    // Final
    int checkbox18 = 0;
    int checkbox19 = +10;
    int count = 0;
    int Totalchecked = panel3.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
        .Where(c => c.Checked).Count();
    int TotalValue = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < TotalValue; i++)
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if ((c is CheckBox) && ((CheckBox)c).Checked)
            {
                count += Convert.ToInt32(c.Text);
            }
        }

    // If you consider, each check box value as a 5, 
    // just multiply Totalchecked * 5
        
    count = count + 1;
    var totalselected = TotalValue;
    TotalValue = Totalchecked * 0;
    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalValue);
}
```

I have tried adding the same code for the `checkbox19` which has it just counting the number of checked boxes verse the values of the checked boxes. For example, `checkbox1` has a value of `0` but `checkbox19` has a value of `13`.trying to make it like a check sheet for grading maneuvers of a vehicle. the first set of boxes would be for any time the vehicle is pulled forward during the maneuver you would check the box the first pull up is a free one any additional one would add one point per additional. i have been able to have it count how many boxes are checked but not the value of the box to have it totaled for score

Comment: Have you debugged your code to see what values are there when it gets to the for loop?  Are you sure TotalValue is not 0?  It would never get in your loop if that is the case.

Comment: says assigned but never used,, sorry kinda new to all this

Comment: That's because you're assigning a bunch of `int` types but never using the values. It's just a compiler warning, but what exactly are all the `int checkboxN = ` lines supposed to be doing?

Comment: Also, there's no need to include a `+` sign before a number. All numbers are considered positive unless they're preceeded by a `-` sign.

Comment: Please add a better description of what you're trying to do and what the problem is. It's really not clear if you're not able to find all the checkboxes, or if you're trying to get rid of the compiler warning, or something else.

Comment: trying to make it like a check sheet for grading maneuvers of a vehicle. the first set of boxes would be for any time the vehicle is pulled forward during the maneuver you would check the box the first pull up is a free one any additional one would add one point per additional. i have been able to have it count how many boxes are checked but not the value of the box to have it totaled for score